# Android: Millis long - loss of precision by one hour

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

basically I have an app which first asks for user input then when user clicks submit it takes current time and stores it in SharedPreferences with following code:

SubmitAction.java

```
ConversePrefs cp = new ConversePrefs(Awake.this);
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
cp.SetStartTime(date.getTime());
```

ConversePrefs.java:

```
 public void SetStartTime(long start){
     SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();  
     editor.putLong("StartTime", start);
     editor.commit();
 }
 public long GetStartTime(){
     SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
     long setting  = settings.getLong("StartTime", 0);
     return setting;
     }
```

After all actions and functionality of app were done, user is brought to new Activity which gets start time and uses it with current time.

FinalActivity.java:

```
    final ConversePrefs cp = new ConversePrefs(this);
    final long start_time = cp.GetStartTime();
    final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss"); 
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());   
    long end_time = date.getTime();
    long final_time = end_time - start_time;
    String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(final_time));
```

dateString ends up showing offset by one hour.
Example:

I clicked Submit button at: 02:40:22 AM
App did all actions and opened new activity in 13 seconds.
I end up having counter saying:
Time Elapsed: 01:00:13

So it adds an extra hour, what could the problem/cause be of this?

I am in UTC timezone by the way if that matters.

Comment: Off by 1 hour almost always means a DST problem.

Comment: @GabeSechan: Not here, though, I think.

Comment: Hmm.  Yeah, in this particular one your answer below is probably right.

Comment: @GabeSechan: On second thoughts, maybe it is a time zone problem, too. Why would it print "00" hours as "1"? I can somewhat understand that it becomes "12" (as in "midnight").

Comment: But even if it was timezone problem, it shouldn't be adding extra hour since it's using same timezone for both: old and new time.

I mean if old time was taken in -1 Timezone
and new time was taken in +0 timezone then yeah it should add an hour, but this is same.

Comment: Daylight Savings: January 1970 was in winter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use a DateFormatter to format a "time elapsed". It's not made for that. What you are actually formatting here is the time portion of some date in January 1970, and you are maybe being tripped by a time zone or DST issue. Why not just print the number of seconds as an integer (or double)? If you already use Commons Lang, there is [DurationFormatUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DurationFormatUtils.html).

Comment: First solution didn't work - the HH format it's still offset by one hour.

Comment: Okay, then it really is a time zone problem. Don't use a DateFormatter here.

Comment: So you are making suggestion to:
Instead of using DateFormatter - Just do:
final_time = NewTime - OldTime;
difference = final_time / 1000;

which gives difference in seconds and then just format it using something like:
hours = difference / 3600
minutes = (difference / 60) % 60
seconds = difference % 60

like that?

Comment: Yes. Maybe you can copy the relevant method from DurationFormatUtils.

Comment: Got it working using this:
    long final_time = end_time - start_time;
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(final_time);
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(final_time);
    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(final_time);

Comment: Actually no I didn't, it keeps counting seconds and making them total rather then resetting them to 0 and starting again. 
Guess I am gonna go with modulus idea and divisions